# sync two threads properly

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Got two threads that are started using AfxBeginThreads and synchronized as something as shown. how to synchronize them properly using Createevent, SetEvent..etc? Can I see the actual code order by which to call each event?. it seem to work but may not be the right implementation.

```
volatile  unsigned char r = 0;

    DWORD thread1(Lpvoid ...)
    {
        WritetoBuffer
        r=1;
    }

    DWORD thread2(Lpvoid ...)
    {
        if(r==1)
        ReadsBuffer
        r=0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves unclear *exactly* what you are trying to achieve: does `thread1` write only once, and does `thread2` read only once? Or does `thread1` constantly write, while `thread2` constantly reads?

You may want to check out the description of the [Producer-Consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) on wikipedia. The page even contains a C++ implementation (which uses new C++11 features, so you may not be able to compile it) that should give you on idea on how to go about implementing this using MFC and the Win32 API.

You can also check out [Using Semaphores: Multithreaded Producer/Consumer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1201/Using-Semaphores-Multithreaded-Producer-Consumer) on CodeProject. The article provides an implementation that uses Windows API functions and explains the situation very well.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: write and read are continuous. Buffer is part of ring buffer.

Comment: Then I think you ought to read the links I provided. Both will give you good ideas on how to go about implementing this.